Blurry screen in VS Code (Windows 11)
Getting blurry screen in VS code while working.
I am working in windows 11. Installed VS-Code and while working in it I am getting a blurry screen. Tried to see the settings but didn't get any specific one.
Can someone please help me how to fix this.


This is usually caused by bad video driver settings. Go to your nvidia control panel (for example), look for any antialiasing settings and similar, set everything to "as set by the application" instead of any overrides.
